# Transit visa on arrival in Kazakhstan

Tags: visas, airports, kazakhstan, transit, visas-on-arrival

I've been told it's possible to get a transit visa on arrival at the airport in Kazakhstan.  Can anyone find me some current details on this - how long it's for, how much it costs, and what's required to get it?

And also, whether it's possible to get on arrival at the land border ...

Comment: A word of advice, get your visa ahead of time. This country is corrupt, unless you give them money under the table, they will try everything possible not to give you the visa. I was traveling with my spouse and an infant, they made us wait 3 hours (in the middle of the night) to issue us a visa. Meanwhile there was a group of ppl that arrived after us, the guy got paid off and issued them a visa right away (the guy working wasn't even descrete about it). I will never travel through this country again.

Comment: @Vee - it's not always that bad, I had trouble in St Petersburg getting one, but getting it from the Krgyzstan side was remarkably straight-forward in the end.  Don't let the corrupt officials put you off what is an amazing country with some fantastic stuff to offer.

Comment: @MarkMayo Perhaps you are right. But understand that for some people such hassle can be deterring. I for my part will never go the US as long as they are hazing people at the border, in the way they are doing it now. There is so much to see in the world and you can have a fulfilled (traveller) live without having visited the US or Kazakhstan.

Comment: Sure, but I for example want to go to the US enough that I'll put up with the border hassles. Flight to Boston is in ...39 hours ;)

Comment: Have a nice trip!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this information](http://www.kazakhstan.orexca.com/visa_kazakhstan.shtml):

> Transit visas through the territory of Kazakhstan **(for 5 days)** are issued with the presence of a visa to a third country (the visiting country) and ticket (ticket for travel through the territory of Kazakhstan).

So you need visa of the country you are going to, and ticket. Note that you must register during first 5 days in Kazakhstan.
You can do it right in airport:

> Customers may receive Kazakhstan transit visa (at the embassy of Kazakhstan in Almaty) airport without invitation, as long as they have visa and through air or railway tickets to a third country.

You may need to push hard. In my experience they will start by saying you can't do it, but will eventually concede. The other problem at Almaty airport is that you need the embassy guy to be there to issue the visa. If you arrive at night he will probably have gone home!

Fares are complicated, but I think this will be helpful (can't determine, is this apply to you or not):

> Single entry up to 30 days tourist visa abroad for 3 days will cost 30 US$, within 1 day - 40 US$;

Also check [official information](http://portal.mfa.kz/portal/page/portal/mfa/en/content/consular/visa_info).

Comment: As to 2012, registration is not needed if you land with a flight at Almaty airport. But (!) be sure to check that you have the correct stamp on the the registration slip (a small note with your details that they give you when stamping your passport). You'll have to keep that slip with you and show it when you leave the country. If you do not have this slip you will have to get back to the nearest town and register there after paying a fine of 100$.